# 'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'system.windows.forms.application' and 'Microsoft.office.interop.word.application'

Tags: c#

Using C# on vs 2012, I am trying to convert a file of type doc to a file of tybe docx but I get two errors
Error1: 'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.windows.forms.application' and 'Microsoft.office.interop.word.application'

Error2: the type 'system.windows.forms.application' has no constructors found

```
Using system.IO
Using Microsoft.office.Interop.word

public void ConvertDocToDocx(string path)
    {
        Application word = new Application();

        if (path.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc"))
        {
            var sourceFile = new FileInfo(path);
            var document = word.Documents.Open(sourceFile.FullName);

            string newFileName = sourceFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".docx");
            document.SaveAs2(newFileName,WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument, 
                             CompatibilityMode: WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2010);

            word.ActiveDocument.Close();
            word.Quit();

            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error 1 is causing error 2, so focus on error 1. You do understand what it's saying, do you? You've written 'Application' but there are two Application classes in namespaces that you have included so it's not sure which one you meant.

Comment: @Rup is right. You probably want to use ```Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application```. In VS you should be able to use the lightbulb on the left side of the line to automatically resolve the error.

Comment: Ok thats solved error1 but not error2

Comment: It might be [`new ApplicationClass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationclass) nowadays - it looks like Application is just an interface.

Comment: No sir, nothing is called new ApplicationClass()

Answer (score 1):

You use both namespaces in that file, you could do:

1. Use full name with namespace eg. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` instead `Application`
2. Declare alias for class by using eg. `using WordApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;`, and than use `WordApp` instead `Application`
3. Remove unused namespace (only if you don't use it)

Example:

```cs
Using system.IO
Using Microsoft.office.Interop.word

public void ConvertDocToDocx(string path)
{
  var word = new Microsoft.office.Interop.word.Application();
  ...
}
```

Comment: When you not use `new Application()` in context of `System.Windows.Forms.Application`, second error shouldn't never show up. Do you use `System.Windows.Forms.Application` anywhere else?